# Can't assign names to legend points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

`pData` is a response from server that I get with `ajax` call.

```
success: function(pData) {
    var data = pData.row; 
    var items = data;
    name = items.map(function(el) {
        return el.NAME;
    });
    broj = items.map(function(el) {
        return el.Y;
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            renderTo: 'chart4',                

        },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
    }
  },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: broj
        }],
        credits: false,
        title: false
    });
}
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/7m5j67s2/

The data that I get is good , the only thing that's missing is that every pice slice is named "Slice", and I can't figure out how to get each part of pie to be called with what I got from the server ( it's contained in the `name` array).

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the data you're passing to Highchart (items) is an array of numbers. you need to add titles to it, like:

```
   series: [{

        data: [
            ['title1',   10],
            ['title2',    9],
            ['title3',    8],
            ['title4',    7],

        ]
    }]
```

This will add titles to your  slices. for your code, you can make a few changes in mapping to `broj`:

```
  broj = items.map(function(el) {
        return [el.NAME, el.Y];
  });
```

then the rest of your code will work ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alihaghighatkhah/10xwbtau))

Comment: I've added a demo that could maybe help you figure out how I'm passing my data.

Comment: @Paran0a I made the above mentioned minor change in your fiddle and it's working now

Comment: @Paran0a I've added a fiddle

Comment: That did it. Thank you!